# Creating a tab plugin

Tags: javascript, optimization, jquery, css, plugin

I am creating a tab plugin. I want to know if there is a better way of doing this or if what I have is good. It works just fine, but there may be some shortcuts or a more optimized way of accomplishing this. I plan to replace the `startTab` variable with an options set, but I am not quite there yet.

[View the current updated version here](http://www.mail-apps.com/tabplugin/TabPluginWorkFile.html)

Here is what I have so far:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
ul.tabNavigation {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.tabNavigation li {
    display: inline;
}
ul.tabNavigation li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
}
.tabViews {
    width: 100%;
    border: #8db2e3 solid 1px;
    clear:both;
    height:18px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    background: url(css/tabs/images/tabs_Lower_Header_Background.png) repeat-x;
}
.tab {
    height: 25px;
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    float:left;
    padding-left: 4px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px
}
.tab .right {
    float:left;
    background:url(css/tabs/images/tab_Selected_Right.png) no-repeat;
    height:25px;
    width: 8px;
}
.tab .content {
    float:left;
    background:url(css/tabs/images/tab_Selected_Content.png) repeat-x;
    height:25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
.tab .left {
    float:left;
    background:url(css/tabs/images/tab_Selected_Left.png) no-repeat;
    height:25px;
    width: 6px;
}
.tabHover {
    height: 25px;
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    float:left;
    padding-left: 4px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.h1 {
    float:left;
    height:25px;
    width: 14px;
}
.h2 {
    float:left;
    height:25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
.h3 {
    float:left;
    height:25px;
    width: 10px;
}
.tabHover:hover .h1 {
    background:url(css/tabs/images/tab_Hover_Right.png) no-repeat;
}
.tabHover:hover .h2 {
    background:url(css/tabs/images/tab_Hover_Content.png) repeat-x;
}
.tabHover:hover .h3 {
    background:url(css/tabs/images/tab_Hover_Left.png) no-repeat;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

$.fn.tabs = function(startTab){
    //Set currentIndex
    var currentIndex = 0;

    //Get all tab views
    var tabViews = $('.tabViews > div',$(this));

    //Current tab container
    var tabsContainer = $(this);
    //Hide all tabView containers
    tabViews.hide();


    //Get all tabs
    var $tabs = $('ul > li', tabsContainer);


    $tabs.each(function(index){
        $('a',$(this)).click(function(){
            changeTab(index);

        });


    });

     //call the changeTab method for the first time and selected the starting tab.
    changeTab(startTab);

    function changeTab(selectedIndex){

        if(selectedIndex != currentIndex){
            switchClass(selectedIndex);
            var previousSelectedTab = $('a',$tabs[currentIndex]);
            var currentSelectedTab = $('a',$tabs[selectedIndex]);

            $(previousSelectedTab.attr('href')).hide();            
            $(currentSelectedTab.attr('href')).show();
            currentIndex = selectedIndex;
        }


    }

     //Method to switch the calles for selected and non selected tabs.
    function switchClass(selectedIndex){        
        $tabs.each(function(index){
                            //Get Child Left, Content, right divs
                            var classBuilder = $('div  > div',$(this))

                            //Current Selected Tab
                            if(index == selectedIndex){
                                var tabContainer = $('a > div',$(this))
                                tabContainer.removeClass('tabHover');
                                tabContainer.addClass('tab');
                                $(classBuilder[0]).removeClass('h3');
                                $(classBuilder[0]).addClass('left');
                                $(classBuilder[1]).removeClass('h2');
                                $(classBuilder[1]).addClass('content');
                                $(classBuilder[2]).removeClass('h1');
                                $(classBuilder[2]).addClass('right');


                            }
                            //Previously selected tab
                            if(index == currentIndex){
                                var tabContainer = $('a > div',$(this))
                                tabContainer.removeClass('tab');
                                tabContainer.addClass('tabHover');

                                $(classBuilder[0]).removeClass('left');
                                $(classBuilder[0]).addClass('h3');
                                $(classBuilder[1]).removeClass('content');
                                $(classBuilder[1]).addClass('h2');
                                $(classBuilder[2]).removeClass('right');
                                $(classBuilder[2]).addClass('h1');
                            }
                            });
    }

}

$(function() {
  $('#rfiTabs').tabs(0);
}); 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="rfiTabs">
  <ul class="tabNavigation">
    <li><a href="#rfiBasic">
      <div class="tab">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="content">Basic</div>
        <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
      </a></li>
    <li><a href="#rfiHome">
      <div class="tabHover">
        <div style="" class="h3"></div>
        <div style="" class="h2">Home</div>
        <div class="h1"></div>
      </div>
      </a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabViews" style="">
    <div id="rfiBasic">Test</div>
    <div id="rfiHome">test this</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I realized I can optimize the left, content, and center part of the tabs by updating the CSS and jQuery for the hover section:

```html
.tabHover .right {
    float:left;
    height:25px;
    width: 14px;
}
.tabHover .content {
    float:left;
    height:25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
.tabHover .left {
    float:left;
    height:25px;
    width: 10px;
}
.tabHover:hover .right {
    background:url(css/tabs/images/tab_Hover_Right.png) no-repeat;
}
.tabHover:hover .content {
    background:url(css/tabs/images/tab_Hover_Content.png) repeat-x;
}
.tabHover:hover .left {
    background:url(css/tabs/images/tab_Hover_Left.png) no-repeat;
}

function switchClass(selectedIndex){        
        $tabs.each(function(index){
                            //Get Child Lef, Content, right divs
                            var classBuilder = $('div  > div',$(this))


                            if(index == selectedIndex){
                                var tabContainer = $('a > div',$(this))
                                tabContainer.removeClass('tabHover');
                                tabContainer.addClass('tab');
                                //$(classBuilder[0]).removeClass('h3');
//                                $(classBuilder[0]).addClass('left');
//                                $(classBuilder[1]).removeClass('h2');
//                                $(classBuilder[1]).addClass('content');
//                                $(classBuilder[2]).removeClass('h1');
//                                $(classBuilder[2]).addClass('right');


                            }

                            if(index == currentIndex){
                                var tabContainer = $('a > div',$(this))
                                tabContainer.removeClass('tab');
                                tabContainer.addClass('tabHover');

                                //$(classBuilder[0]).removeClass('left');
//                                $(classBuilder[0]).addClass('h3');
//                                $(classBuilder[1]).removeClass('content');
//                                $(classBuilder[1]).addClass('h2');
//                                $(classBuilder[2]).removeClass('right');
//                                $(classBuilder[2]).addClass('h1');
                            }
                            });
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could remove tab navigation from html and create it dynamically in plugin so the html will look like this:

```
<div id="rfiTabs">
  <div class="tabViews" style="">
    <div id="rfiBasic">Test</div>
    <div id="rfiHome">test this</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

you don't need to call

```
var tabsContainer = $(this);
```

this is already jQuery object

inside switchClass function you call $(this) 3 times you can call it once and stor the value

```
var $this = $(this);
```

you get element from jQuery object and then wrap it again.

```
$(classBuilder[0]).removeClass('h3');
```

you could use eq jquery method

```
classBuilder.eq(0).removeClass('h3');
```

instead

```
if(index == selectedIndex){

} 
if(index == currentIndex){

}
```

use

```
if(index == selectedIndex){

} else if(index == currentIndex){

}
```

you don't need to check if `index == currentIndex` if `index == selectedIndex`

this code is repeaded twice but with different class names create a function for it (it looks almost the same — if you see something like this always create new function)

```
$(classBuilder[0]).removeClass('h3');
$(classBuilder[0]).addClass('left');
$(classBuilder[1]).removeClass('h2');
$(classBuilder[1]).addClass('content');
$(classBuilder[2]).removeClass('h1');
$(classBuilder[2]).addClass('right');
```

and you can chain jquery methods:

```
classBuilder.eq(0).removeClass('h3').addClass('left');
classBuilder.eq(1).removeClass('h2').addClass('content');
classBuilder.eq(2).removeClass('h1').addClass('right');
```

you don't need to iterate over $tabs

```
function switchClass(selectedIndex){ 
   $tabs.eq(selectedIndex)
```

and I think that this:

```
var classBuilder = $tabs.eq(selectedIndex).find('div  > div');
```

will be the same as

```
var classBuilder = $('div  > div',$(this))
```

and this:

```
if(index == currentIndex){
    var tabContainer = $('a > div',$(this))
    tabContainer.removeClass('tab');
    tabContainer.addClass('tabHover');
```

is the same as

$tabs.eq(currentIndex).find('a > div').removeClass('tab').addClass('tabHover');

and at the end of the script you should return `this` so it could be chained

```
$('#rfiTabs').tabs(0).css('background-color', 'red');
```

you can also do this:

return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      //and create your tabs here
   });

so if you call it

```
$('.myalltabs').tabs(0);
```

it will create tabs for every element that have `.myalltabs` class

**Update**

if you your jquery object have multiple elements (But this is Something Completely Different)

```
$.fn.tabs = function(n) {

    var = tabcontainer = $('<div/>').attr('class', 'mainTabClass')
             .appendTo($('body'));

    var nav = $('<ul>').addClass('navigation').appendTo(tabcontainer);
    this.each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       var id = $this.attr('id');
       $('<li>').append('<a>').appendTo(nav).children().
          attr('href', '#' + id).html($this.attr('name'));
    }).addClass('tabContent').detach().appendTo(tabcontainer);

    nav.find('li a').click(function() {
      tabcontainer.find('tabContent').removeClass('selected');
      tabcontainer.find($(this).attr('href')).addClass('selected');
    }).eq(n).addClass('selected');
};
```

in this case you need only

```
.selected {
   display: block;
}
.mainTabClass .tabContent {
   display: none;
}

  ....
  <div id="home" name="Home Page">this is home</div>
  ....
  <div id="about" name="About me">this is about</div>
  ....
```

name attribute in case you won't different name than id.

```
$('#home, #about').tabs(1);
```

and you will have

```
<div class="mainTabClass">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#home">Home Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabContent" id="home">this is home</div>
  <div class="tabContent selected" id="about">this is about</div>
</div>
```

I don't know why you have repeated `left`, `right` and `content` for every tab, if you need to use those - create one instance and change it on click (in case you will have 100 tabs you will have 3 DOM elements instead of 300)

Comment: Do you think I should pass a tab array into the plugin? So instead of creating the tabs in a list format just create them inside the Jquery?

Comment: You can created it from jquery objects - $('ul li').tabs(0) this will create tabs from all li elements instead of creating multiply tabs from children inside li element, in this case you can use something like this $('div.foo, div.bar, div#baz').tabs(0) and it will create tabs from whatever are in `this` inside the plugin, so panels from your tabs can be in different palaces in the DOM.

Comment: I don't quite understand how my left,conent,right div structure would fit into your suggestion. Would you mind showing me an example of what you are saying?

Comment: you create tabNavigation and left,content,right divs dynamically and call `this.hide().detach().appendTo($('<div>').addClass('tabViews').appendTo(dynamicly_created_rfiTabs));`

Comment: or `this.hide().detach().wrapAll('<div class="tabViews"/>'). parent().appendTo(dynamicly_created_rfiTabs);` if you create a plugin you should minimize the amount of code that is needed to use it.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks!!!! I think I will still add, into the options, a way to pass in an array of tabs (Name, selected, tab view to display onclick). Thoughts?

Comment: "I don't know why you have repeated left, right and content for every tab"...I used these divs for the graphics on the tab. This is so the content area will be dynamic. If anyone has a better suggestion, please let me know.

Comment: if you want to set a graphic in the tab you could use background-image for link you can also use sprites (image for all tabs in two states and changing background-position css attribute on hover), and if left and right are images for arrows and content is image for button - then put those one this and on hover change the class for the content `nav_content.addClass('selected');` and in css `.nav .selected { background-position: <position in sprite for selected tab image> }` you can read about sprites here http://goo.gl/ofScM and here http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Thanks a ton, jcubic. I have avoided using CSS sprites for far too long. I guess it is time to go that toute! Thanks again for all your comments!